# Minimum difference between timestamps with window function

Tags: sql-server-2014, window-functions

I have the following base data sets.

I would like to know the ProcessStepLast time stamp for each ProcessStepOne record.

- The latest ProcessStepOne record for each PersonId should have the latest ProcessStepLast record for the same PersonId.
- The next latest ProcessStepOne record should have the next latest ProcessStepLast record and so on.
- A ProcessStepLast record can only belong to one ProcessStepOne record.
- There will always be at least one ProcessStepOne per PersonId.
- There may be zero, one or more ProcessStepLast records per PersonId.

I'd prefer not to join on timestamps if possible and wanted to know if this was a candidate for a window function? I've given it a go, but can't quite get there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Id       PersonId    ProcessStepOne
1084465  11802   2019-01-18 15:45:44.000
1084507  11802   2019-01-18 16:07:22.000

Id       PersonId    ProcessStepLast
1016970  11802   2019-01-24 12:51:52.600
1016996  11802   2019-01-24 12:55:21.953
1013472  11802   2019-01-24 12:51:45.803 

Id       PersonId    ProcessStepOne            ProcessStepLast
1084465  11802   2019-01-18 15:45:44.000   2019-01-24 12:51:52.600
1084507  11802   2019-01-18 16:07:22.000   2019-01-24 12:55:21.953
```

Comment: is there a 1:1 relationship between both tables? is there always a "process step last" to a "process step one"?

Comment: I've edited the question to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output does not seem to completely line up with what you describe, because the `2019-01-24 12:51:45.803` record from the second data set does not appear anywhere.  But a general solution here which might work would be to union together your two tables, and then just aggregate in pairs:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Id, PersonId, ProcessStepOne AS ProcessStep, 1 AS source,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY ProcessStepOne) rn
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, PersonId, ProcessStepTwo, 2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY ProcessStepTwo)
    FROM table2
)

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN source = 1 THEN Id END) AS Id,
    PersonId,
    MIN(ProcessStep) AS ProcessStepOne,
    MAX(ProcessStep) AS ProcessStepTwo
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    PersonId,
    rn;
```

[image]

### Demo

As a side note, the computed column `source` which I introduce in the union query CTE is there so that we can remember which `Id` value corresponds to the first table.  This is to meet your requirement of using the first source `Id` labels in the expected output.